# which MapR version is supported for Java17?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17, mapr

As I'm upgrading Spring framework to 6x, and for that, Java needs to be upgraded too so which MapR version needs to be used as I'm getting connectivity failures.
Current upgraded spring version is 6.0.14, spring-boot is 3.1.6

I've tried 6.1.0.0-mapr version but it didn't work, earlier it used to work with spring 5x and java8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use mapr 7 jars as java 17 supported only on mapr7